# Should moderators see the new "We have posts flagged for moderator attention (...) " link?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderator-tools, flags

I mean... they know already.

Isn't it redundant? Is there a benefit I'm missing?
I guess you have an "unread" count there, but we already see the posts dimmed when we saw them in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed redundant information for moderators, it won't show for ♦ moderators after the next build (in about 30 minutes).